# How to display 3 weeks in a row in jQuery UI DatePicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Currently, I am working on a calendar layout that has 3 weeks in a row. How I can achieve this via jQuery UI DatePicker? Please Help.

[calendar layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goMwm.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hello If you want to something like below

[image]

then you just need to set **numberOfMonths** attribute as below

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
```

and just make sure you are below version and then you can customize your view.

- 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js version.

Comment: I want one calendar per row as shown in the shared screenshot.